# How does Django Know the Order to Render Form Fields?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

If I have a Django form such as:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = forms.CharField()
    sender = forms.EmailField()
```

And I call the as_table() method of an instance of this form, Django will render the fields as the same order as specified above.

My question is how does Django know the order that class variables where defined?

(Also how do I override this order, for example when I want to add a field from the classe's **init** method?)

Comment: probably related, is that python dicts now return items in the order they are added, not in a random order depending on how they hash. Namespaces are usually dicts (`__slots__` providing an exception?)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I went ahead and answered my own question.  Here's the answer for future reference:

In Django `form.py` does some dark magic using the `__new__` method to load your class variables ultimately into `self.fields` in the order defined in the class.  `self.fields` is a Django `SortedDict` instance (defined in `datastructures.py`).

So to override this, say in my example you wanted sender to come first but needed to add it in an **init** method, you would do:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = forms.CharField()
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        forms.Form.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        #first argument, index is the position of the field you want it to come before
        self.fields.insert(0,'sender',forms.EmailField(initial=str(time.time())))
```

Comment: You can define the 'sender' field as normal at the top and then use a variation on your insert line: `self.fields.insert( 0, 'sender', self.fields['sender'] )`

Comment: This no longer works in Django 1.7 because form fields use OrderedDict which does not support append.  See my updated answer below ( too long for comment )...

Answer (score 103):

New to Django 1.9 is **[Form.field_order](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.field_order)** and **[Form.order_fields()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.order_fields)**.

```
# forms.Form example
class SignupForm(forms.Form):

    password = ...
    email = ...
    username = ...

    field_order = ['username', 'email', 'password']


# forms.ModelForm example
class UserAccount(forms.ModelForm):

    custom_field = models.CharField(max_length=254)

    def Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email')

    field_order = ['username', 'custom_field', 'password']
```

Comment: as of 1.9 this should be the answer new searchers should look at, obviously still works in 1.10

Comment: Note: it's not "fields_order" but "field_order"  (no 's')

Comment: You can even specify just a subset of the form fields you want ordered

Comment: Still works and is the best answer for Django 3.0

Answer (score 90):

**[NOTE: this answer is now pretty completely outdated - please see the discussion below it, and more recent answers].**

If `f` is a form, its fields are `f.fields`, which is a `django.utils.datastructures.SortedDict`  (it presents the items in the order they are added). After form construction f.fields has a keyOrder attribute, which is a list containing the field names in the order they should be presented. You can set this to the correct ordering (though you need to exercise care to ensure you don't omit items or add extras).

Here's an example I just created in my current project:

```
class PrivEdit(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(ModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.fields.keyOrder = [
            'super_user',
            'all_districts',
            'multi_district',
            'all_schools',
            'manage_users',
            'direct_login',
            'student_detail',
            'license']
    class Meta:
        model = Privilege
```

Comment: For some time now, the fields will be ordered as specified by the 'fields' attribute of a ModelForm. From  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form: The order in which the fields names are specified in that list is respected when the form renders them. This only works for ModelForms - your approach is still quite useful for regular forms, especially in form subclasses that add additional fields.

Comment: This works when you're doing funky stuff overriding some fields but not others. +1

Comment: "This" being Chris Lawlor's suggestion? This answer is old enough that it's probably no longer current (but was probably good for 1.2). It's important to make sure that unreliable information gets flagged, otherwise newcomers don't know what to trust. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 11):

Fields are listed in the order they are defined in ModelClass._meta.fields. But if you want to change order in Form, you can do by using keyOrder function.
For example :

```
class ContestForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Contest
    exclude=('create_date', 'company')

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ContestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields.keyOrder = [
        'name',
        'description',
        'image',
        'video_link',
        'category']
```

Answer (score 6):

With Django >= 1.7  your must modify `ContactForm.base_fields` as below:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

...

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    ...

ContactForm.base_fields = OrderedDict(
    (k, ContactForm.base_fields[k])
    for k in ['your', 'field', 'in', 'order']
)
```

This trick is used in Django Admin `PasswordChangeForm`: [Source on Github](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.7/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L338)

Comment: Funny, I seeked out ordering of fields when trying to figure out why subclassing `PasswordChangeForm` changed the order of the fields, so your example happened to be very useful to me. It seems that it's because `base_fields` doesn't get carried over to the subclass. The solution seems to be saying `PasswordChangeFormSubclass.base_fields = PasswordChangeForm.base_fields` after the definition of `PasswordChangeFormSubclass

Comment: @orblivion: use `ContactForm.base_fields[k]` when building the ordered dict. There is a typo n the answer, I'll edit

Answer (score 5):

Form fields have an attribute for creation order, called `creation_counter`. `.fields` attribute is a dictionary, so simple adding to dictionary and changing `creation_counter` attributes in all fields to reflect new ordering should suffice (never tried this, though).

Answer (score 5):

Use a counter in the Field class. Sort by that counter:

```
import operator
import itertools

class Field(object):
    _counter = itertools.count()
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = Field._counter.next()
        self.name = ''
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Field(%r)" % self.name

class MyForm(object):
    b = Field()
    a = Field()
    c = Field()

    def __init__(self):
        self.fields = []
        for field_name in dir(self):
            field = getattr(self, field_name)
            if isinstance(field, Field):
                field.name = field_name
                self.fields.append(field)
        self.fields.sort(key=operator.attrgetter('count'))

m = MyForm()
print m.fields # in defined order
```

Output:

```
[Field('b'), Field('a'), Field('c')]
```

---

Answer (score 4):

If either `fields = '__all__'`:

```
class AuthorForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = '__all__'
```

or `exclude` are used:

```
class PartialAuthorForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        exclude = ['title']
```

Then Django references the order of fields **as defined in the model**. This just caught me out, so I thought I'd mention it. It's referenced in the [ModelForm docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/):

> If either of these are used, the order the fields appear in the form will be the order the fields are defined in the model, with ManyToManyField instances appearing last.

Comment: Indeed, the default order in Django 3 is as declared in the model, and this fortunately seems true even if you change the order after the model has been migrated (i.e. it's the current declaration order not the the order of the fields in the database if any). That's great, by moving them around I can order them on the default form ...

Answer (score 4):

As of Django 1.7 forms use OrderedDict which does not support the append operator.  So you have to rebuild the dictionary from scratch...

```
class ChecklistForm(forms.ModelForm):

  class Meta:
    model = Checklist
    fields = ['name', 'email', 'website']

  def __init__(self, guide, *args, **kwargs):
    self.guide = guide
    super(ChecklistForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    new_fields = OrderedDict()
    for tier, tasks in guide.tiers().items():
      questions = [(t['task'], t['question']) for t in tasks if 'question' in t]
      new_fields[tier.lower()] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        label=tier,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        choices=questions,
        help_text='desired set of site features'
      )

    new_fields['name'] = self.fields['name']
    new_fields['email'] = self.fields['email']
    new_fields['website'] = self.fields['website']
    self.fields = new_fields
```

Comment: Since python 3.2 you can use OrderedDict.move_to_end() to prepend or append items.

Answer (score 3):

For future reference: things have changed a bit since newforms. This is one way of reordering fields from base formclasses you have no control over:

```
def move_field_before(form, field, before_field):
    content = form.base_fields[field]
    del(form.base_fields[field])
    insert_at = list(form.base_fields).index(before_field)
    form.base_fields.insert(insert_at, field, content)
    return form
```

Also, there's a little bit of documentation about the SortedDict that `base_fields` uses here: http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SortedDict

Comment: Using 'fields' in my class Meta was working for me (with a ModelForm) until I had a reason to set an initial value for a foreign key field using MyFormSet.form.base_fields, at which point the order in 'fields' was no longer respected. My solution was actually just to re-order the fields in the underlying model.

Answer (score 3):

To add something, you can use this (Django 3+):

```
class ...(forms.ModelForm):
    field = ...

    class Meta:
        model = Xxxxxx
        fields = '__all__'
    
    field_order = ['field', '__all__']
```

`__all__` works

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to order fields in django 1.9 forms is to use `field_order` in your form [Form.field_order](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.field_order)

Here is a small example

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
     subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
     message = forms.CharField()
     sender = forms.EmailField()
     field_order = ['sender','message','subject']
```

This will show everything in the order you specified in `field_order` dict.

Answer (score 1):

Using `fields` in inner `Meta` class is what worked for me on `Django==1.6.5`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
Example form declaration with custom field order.
"""

from django import forms

from app.models import AppModel


class ExampleModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    An example model form for ``AppModel``.
    """
    field1 = forms.CharField()
    field2 = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = AppModel
        fields = ['field2', 'field1']
```

As simple as that.

Comment: seems like this method is only valid for modelform, the normal form `django.forms` does not work

Answer (score 1):

I've used this to move fields about:

```
def move_field_before(frm, field_name, before_name):
    fld = frm.fields.pop(field_name)
    pos = frm.fields.keys().index(before_name)
    frm.fields.insert(pos, field_name, fld)
```

This works in 1.5 and I'm reasonably sure it still works in more recent versions.

Answer (score 1):

None of these answers worked for me, Actually, you do not have to do anything custom, you can just order the fields in the order you want in your Model class. For eg ... the below code

```
from django.db import models


class Student(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "categories"

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    nick_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Your admin interface for model Will display the fields exactly in the same order in which you have declared in this case it will be `(id, name, nick_name )`

Answer (score 1):

The order of the fields in the form depends on the order of the enumeration in the View , tested in Django 4.0.5.

```
class Sec_CreateView(CreateView):
    model = Sec
    template_name = 'forms/sec_create.html'
    fields = ['rto', 'ssid', 'lic', 'IPv4', 'vlans']
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the meta class that is used in defining the form class.  I think it keeps an internal list of the fields and if you insert into the middle of the list it might work.  It has been a while since I looked at that code.