# How can I order fields in Django ModelForm?

Tags: python, sorting, django-forms

I have an 'order' Model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
     date_time=models.DateTimeField()
     # other stuff
```

And I'm using Django ModelForm class to render a form, but I want to display date and time widgets separately. I've came up with this:

```
class Form(forms.ModelForm): 
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        exclude = ('date_time',)
        date = forms.DateField()
        time = forms.TimeField()
```

The problem is that I want to put these fields somewhere between 'other stuff'

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does Django Know the Order to Render Form Fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350799/how-does-django-know-the-order-to-render-form-fields)

Answer (score 69):

You can use:

```
class Meta:
    fields = [ ..., 'date', 'time', ... ]
```

See the docs: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-order-of-fields

Comment: This is the correct answer, while I just want to mention that fields=[...] can contain user defined fields.

Comment: Exactly, and when you try to override `__init__` calling `self.fields.keyOrder = [ <model and user defined fields > ...]` instead - you will get problems (exceptions etc.).

Comment: As of Jan2021/Django 3.0, the documentation you've linked to doesn't feature a "changing the order of fields" section.  If I use the solution you've given, Django throws a "ModelForm has no model class specified" error.

Comment: As for Django 3.1 and certainly for previous versions, readonly fields are always put at last.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Lukasz answer, in Django 2.0 the complete admin form registration with field ordering would look like the following:

*models.py*

```
class Order(models.Model):
    date_time = models.DateTimeField()
    # other fields
```

*admin.py*

```
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    datef = forms.DateField()
    timef = forms.TimeField()

    class Meta:
      model = Order
      exclude = ['date_time']
      fields = (
          'datef',
          'timef',
          # other fields
      )

class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = OrderForm

admin.site.register(Order, OrderAdmin)
```

Note that date and time fields are defined in ModelForm class and not in Meta class.

Comment: This requires all fields to be specified... is there a way to do it like how field_order works for regular forms? Where the rest of the fields are appended to the end.