# how to change the order of the fields?

Tags: python, django

please help change the order of the form fields on the screen.

I created the following model:

```
class UserProfile(User):
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=30, 
        blank=True,
    )

    address = models.EmailField(
        max_length=50, 
        blank=True,
    )   

    objects = UserManager()
```

then combined field of this model built with fields of the registration form:

```
class MyRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm): 
    username = forms.CharField(
        label='username',
        help_text='',
        required=True,
    )

    password1 = forms.CharField(
        label='pass1',
        help_text='',
        required=True,
    )   

    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label='pass2',
        help_text='',
        required=True,
    )   

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('status', 'address')
```

as a result the user sees on the display field in this order: 
status, address, username, pass1, pass2

but I need the user to see the screen fields in the following order:
username, address, pass1, pass2, status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types):

> The generated Form class will have a form field for every model field
>   specified, in the order specified in the `fields` attribute.

```
class MyRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm): 
    ...
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('username', 'address', 'password1', 'password2', 'status')
```

See also: [How can I order fields in Django ModelForm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893471/how-can-i-order-fields-in-django-modelform)