# Can I count on the order of field validation in a Django form?

Tags: django, validation

I have a Django form with a username and email field.  I want to check the email isn't already in use by a user:

```
def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
    if User.objects.filter(email=email).count() != 0:
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("Email not available."))
    return email
```

This works, but raises some false negatives because the email might already be in the database for the user named in the form.  I want to change to this:

```
def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
    username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
    if User.objects.filter(email=email,  username__ne=username).count() != 0:
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("Email not available."))
    return email
```

The Django docs say that all the validation for one field is done before moving onto the next field.  If email is cleaned before username, then `cleaned_data["username"]` won't be available in `clean_email`.  But the docs are unclear as to what order the fields are cleaned in.  I declare username before email in the form, does that mean I'm safe in assuming that username is cleaned before email?

I could read the code, but I'm more interested in what the Django API is promising, and knowing that I'm safe even in future versions of Django.

Comment: What if the user changed his/her username in the form? Then `username__ne=username` won't exclude that user because the old username will still be in the database.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Django docs claim that it's in order of the field definition.

But I've found that it doesn't always hold up to that promise.
Source: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/

> These methods are run in the order
>   given above, one field at a time. That
>   is, for each field in the form (in the
>   order they are declared in the form
>   definition), the Field.clean() method
>   (or its override) is run, then
>   clean_(). Finally, once
>   those two methods are run for every
>   field, the Form.clean() method, or its
>   override, is executed.

Comment: that's the paragraph I read, and it doesn't claim the fields are process in order. "These methods are run in the order given above" refers to the bullet list of methods: to_python(), validate(), run_validators(), clean(), clean_<fieldname>(), form.clean().

Comment: That's not true Ned Batchelder, look at this part: `for each field in the form (in the order they are declared in the form definition)`

Answer (score 9):

### Update

`.keyOrder` no longer works. I believe this should work instead:

```
from collections import OrderedDict


class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    …

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        field_order = ['has_custom_name', 'name']
        reordered_fields = OrderedDict()
        for fld in field_order:
            reordered_fields[fld] = self.fields[fld]
        for fld, value in self.fields.items():
            if fld not in reordered_fields:
                reordered_fields[fld] = value
        self.fields = reordered_fields
```

#### Previous Answer

There are things that can alter form order regardless of how you declare them in the form definition. One of them is if you're using a `ModelForm`, in which case unless you have both fields declared in `fields` under `class Meta` they are going to be in an unpredictable order.

Fortunately, **there is a reliable solution**.

#### You can control the field order in a form by setting `self.fields.keyOrder`.

Here's some sample code you can use:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    has_custom_name = forms.BooleanField(label="Should it have a custom name?")
    name = forms.CharField(required=False, label="Custom name")

    class Meta:
        model = Widget
        fields = ['name', 'description', 'stretchiness', 'egginess']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ordered_fields = ['has_custom_name', 'name']
        self.fields.keyOrder = ordered_fields + [k for k in self.fields.keys() if k not in ordered_fields]

    def clean_name(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        if data.get('has_custom_name') and not data.get('name'):
            raise forms.ValidationError("You must enter a custom name.")
        return data.get('name')
```

With `keyOrder` set, `has_custom_name` will be validated (and therefore present in `self.cleaned_data`) before `name` is validated.

Comment: I should add that credit goes to Selene's answer to a related SO question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1133470/255918

Comment: It really works. It isn't an exact answer to "can I count on the order of field validation", but it's a solution if you want to set the order.

Comment: @Jonathan It looks like Django is now using an OrderedDict to store the fields. I'll put some updated code in my answer.

Answer (score 8):

There's no promise that the fields are processed in any particular order. The official recommendation is that any validation that depends on more than one field should be done in the form's `clean()` method, rather than the field-specific `clean_foo()` methods.

Comment: That's not correct. There is a promise on the processing order of the fields. It's just not kept well in all versions. Perhaps the newer Django versions do hold up to this promise but I haven't verified that.

Answer (score 3):

> The Form subclass’s clean() method. This method can perform any
>   validation that requires access to multiple fields from the form at
>   once. This is where you might put in things to check that if field A
>   is supplied, field B must contain a valid email address and the like.
>   The data that this method returns is the final cleaned_data attribute
>   for the form, so don’t forget to return the full list of cleaned data
>   if you override this method (by default, Form.clean() just returns
>   self.cleaned_data).

Copy-paste from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#using-validators

This means that if you want to check things like the value of the email and the parent_email are not the same you should do it inside that function. i.e:

```
from django import forms

from myapp.models import User

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    parent_email = forms.EmailField(required = True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email',)

    def clean_email(self):
        # Do whatever validation you want to apply to this field.
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        #... validate and raise a forms.ValidationError Exception if there is any error
        return email

    def clean_parent_email(self):
        # Do the all the validations and operations that you want to apply to the
        # the parent email. i.e: Check that the parent email has not been used 
        # by another user before.
        parent_email = self.cleaned_data['parent_email']
        if User.objects.filter(parent_email).count() > 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Another user is already using this parent email')
        return parent_email

    def clean(self):
        # Here I recommend to user self.cleaned_data.get(...) to get the values 
        # instead of self.cleaned_data[...] because if the clean_email, or 
        # clean_parent_email raise and Exception this value is not going to be 
        # inside the self.cleaned_data dictionary.

        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email', '')
        parent_email = self.cleaned_data.get('parent_email', '')
        if email and parent_email and email == parent_email:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Email and parent email can not be the same')
        return self.cleaned_data
```