# Django self.cleaned_data Keyerror

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm writing a Django website and i'm writing my own validation for a form :

```
class CreateJobOpportunityForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    start_date = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget)
    end_date = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget)

    def clean_start_date(self):
        start_date = self.cleaned_data['start_date']
        end_date = self.cleaned_data['end_date']
        if start_date > end_date :
            raise forms.ValidationError("Start date should be before end date.")
        return start_date
```

but when the start_date is less than end_date it says :

```
KeyError at /create_job_opportunity
'end_date'
```

why doesn't it recognize the `'end_date'` key?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since one field depends on another field, it's best if you did your cleaning in the `clean` method for the form, instead of the individual `clean_field` method.

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(CreateJobOpportunityForm, self).clean()
    end_date = cleaned_data['end_date']
    start_date = cleaned_data['start_date']
    # do your cleaning here
    return cleaned_data
```

Else you would have to ensure that your `end_date` field gets cleaned before `start_date`.

Answer (score 4):

This happen because you trying to get clean_data of end_date before checking end_date is valid or not. if you declare end_date before the start_date in this case end_date is validated, after that clean_start_date is called.
Declare end_date before the start_date like this :

```
class CreateJobOpportunityForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    end_date = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget)
    start_date = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget)

    def clean_start_date(self):
        start_date = self.cleaned_data['start_date']
        end_date = self.cleaned_data['end_date']
        if start_date > end_date :
            raise forms.ValidationError("Start date should be before end date.")
        return start_date
```

Comment: it fixed it, but what should I do if I want start_date and end_date in my order?

Comment: write a init method and do this :
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        forms.Form.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

        self.fields.insert(0,'name',forms.CharField())

Comment: Read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913589/django-forms-inheritance-and-order-of-form-fields

Comment: yes, by default, clean_fieldname() method will be called as the field definition order

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
end_date = self.cleaned_data['end_date']
```

with

```
end_date = self.data.get('end_date')
```

OR

Clean `end_date` field before `start_date` .

Comment: self.data.get('end_date') returns a string and prevent doing '<' comparisons.