# How to order a Model form field created dynamically in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a modelform PropertyBuildingForm

I have added an extra field(block) to it. This field is **coming last** in the order of the PropertyBuildingForm. How can I change the order of this field ?

I have seen this question [Form Field order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350799/how-does-django-know-the-order-to-render-form-fields). But it does not show this specific case. I want the block field to come first.

```
class PropertyBuildingForm(ModelForm):
    block = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Select())
    class Meta:
        model = PropertyBuilding
        exclude = ('property','parcel','images')
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):

        super( PropertyBuildingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['year_built'].widget.attrs['class'] = "datetimepicker"       
        self.fields['number_of_floors'].required = True        
        self.fields['block'].required = False
        self.fields['block'].widget.attrs['class'] = "sez-block-building"

    def clean_block(self):
        block = self.cleaned_data['block']      
        return block
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the `fields` attribute in `Meta`:

```
class PropertyBuildingForm(ModelForm):
    block = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Select())
    class Meta:
        model = PropertyBuilding
        fields = ('block', 'year_built', 'number_of_floors')
```